# How can I animate hair particles by hand?

Tags: animation, particles, hair

Hey on the goosebery branch there was a possibility of animating hair through shape keys, I'm wondering when we will have this feature available ? In my project I need to make a cloth land on a grass field and need to have the grass react accordingly, this is impossible to do dynamically without hair penetrating the cloth. Any Idea on how I can achieve this without having to spend a huge amount of time using goosebery build and lacking 2,5 years of features ?

Thanks in advance